# Dynamics crm 2011 get subgrid selected cell value

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011, subgrid

I need to get specific cell value from selected subgrid rows, i've foud a code to attach click event to the subgrid, but it retreive the name or ID fo the row, how to get the cells value?, the code i sue is below :

```
function ReadSelectedSubGridRecords() {
    if (document.getElementById('Contacts')) {
        var grid = document.getElementById('Contacts').control;
        var ids = grid.get_selectedRecords();
        for (var rowNo = 0; rowNo < grid.get_selectedRecords().length; rowNo++)
            alert(grid.get_selectedRecords()[rowNo].Name);
    }
}

function Form_OnLoad() {
    if (document.getElementById('Contacts')) {
        var grid = document.getElementById('Contacts');
        if (grid.attachEvent) {
            grid.attachEvent('onclick', ReadSelectedSubGridRecords);
        }

    }
    else {
        setTimeout("Form_OnLoad();", 2000);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call CRM to retrieve record fields using ID you have retrieved. You may use OData REST endpoint. See sample in [Dynamics CRM SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24004) \SDK\SampleCode\JS\RESTEndpoint\JavaScriptRESTDataOperations folder.

Add all provided libraries to your form and update your code to retrieve needed records.

Comment: Thanks, That's what i did, i was asking if there is another way.